# Html Agility Pack creating irrelevant characters on save html file in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am working on project using asp.net mvc3 C# . I want to change some html element

attributes by c# like width , height etc. I have a simple **(_Layout.cshtml)** file

```
    <html> <head>
    <link href="@Url.Content("file.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <body>

     <a href="#" id="link1" title="@Function.ConfigElement("FacebookLink")" ></a>

     </body>
    </head> </html>
```

So i am using html agility pack to load and save this file

```
HtmlDocument doc= new HtmlDocument();

doc.load("_Layout.cshtml");

doc.GetElementbyId("link1").Attributes.Add("title", "@Function.ConfigElement("NewLink")");

doc.save("_Layout.cshtml");
```

After saving file output is like this

```
<html> <head>
        <link href="@Url.Content("file.css")"="" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <body>

         <a href="#" id="link1" title="@Function.ConfigElement("NewLink")"="" ></a>

         </body>
        </head> </html>
```

in `(link href)` and `(anchor title)` saving some extra characters

How can i avoid this problem ..
Is there any other solution for parse html in c# for asp.net mvc.

Actually I want to add some server side function in these html element attributes

Comment: I suppose you could just do a `string.Replace("=\"\"", "");` to strip out the extra characters.  That *is* a little weird, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As StackOverflow's syntax highlight subtly hints, your HTML is extremely invalid.

```
href="@Url.Content("file.css")"
```

This is actually two attributes: `href="@Url.Content("` and `file.css")"`. (which has no value)

You can't use an HTML parser to parse Razor markup.
Instead, you should use the actual Razor parser.

Comment: Any example/reference for reading/modifying .cshtml files using Razor parser?

Answer (score 1):

CSCHTML is **not** HTML. It is mix of CS, special scripts and optionally HTML - so HtmlAgilityPack is not a good tool to read/manipulate it.

Why it happens in particular:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("file.css")"
```

Form HTML point of view there are 2 attributes and (href and file.css) plus strange ")" unexpected text. Somehow AgilityPack tries to make sense of it and outputs whatever you got.

Comment: Actually, the `")"` is part of the second attribute. (since there is no `=`)

Comment: @SLaks, probably - have not read HTML spec that carefully to know if attribute name ends on "=" or anything that is not letters... In any case it just not reasonable HTML element. (you already gave correct answer :) )