# Razor parser to read .cshtml files

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Like we have HtmlAgilityPack dll to read .aspx pages and we can get all the script/style references using HtmlNodeCollection class and methods inside in the dll, How can we get all the script/style references in .cshtml pages in MVC using Razor parser.

I have read about Razor Parser being an option to read .cshtml pages, but I have no idea about what it actually is? Please provide complete details on how it works, how it reads all the script/style reference syntaxes in .cshtml, what Razor parser actually is, any kind of information leading to the solution of my question is most welcome.

Using HtmlAgilityPack, I have below lines of code to read script/style references in .aspx pages:

```
HtmlNodeCollection bodyNode_Script = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script");
HtmlNodeCollection bodyNode_Style = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//link");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you already tried; can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Razor parser parses Razor Syntax and converts it to C# executable code. It is not designed to do the same work as the HtmlAgilityPack. If you want to get the script and style references in a rendered .cshtml file, you would use the HtmlAgilityPack for that in the same way as you would with .aspx files (or .php, .html, .jsp etc files).

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning earlier, But I am getting irrelevant characters after using HtmlAgilityPack for .cshtml files.

here is the link for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750804/html-agility-pack-creating-irrelevant-characters-on-save-html-file-in-c-sharp

If there is another option for .cshtml other than HtmlAgilityPack, Please recommend.

Comment: I've got no idea what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to process raw .cshtml files? What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: I just want all the script/style references in .cshtml files using HtmlAgilityPack or Razor parser. Since HtmlAgilityPack creates irrelevant characters, I was looking at some other option like Razor Parser.

Comment: So are you trying to parse raw cshtml files?

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack is designed for parsing HTML. The content of a Razor file doesn't meet that definition. You are using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Kindly let me know, what should be done. HtmlAgilityPack or Razor Parser?
I have already stated the problem with HtmlAgilityPack in the link I shared. Please tell me, How should I proceed further?

Comment: Given that the HtmlAgilityPack is the wrong tool for the job, I recommend you look for an alternative way to parse your file contents. If it was me, I'd look at regular expressions. Or maybe host the Razor engine yourself like this: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2010/Dec/27/Hosting-the-Razor-Engine-for-Templating-in-NonWeb-Applications